# Use tag from wiki when clicking on Ask Question

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, tag-wiki

I want to point out a scenario that could help improve user experience when visiting a tag wiki from an external source.

When companies come to an SE site for their 'product support' questions, [like Microsoft did for their OneDrive product](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283257/993547), they are asked to point to the tag wiki to guide their users to ask the right questions in the right way. I think this is very useful to guide new users their way around here.

However, when you want to ask a question from a tag wiki, the Ask Question page doesn't use the tag already available on the previous page. Should we make it a little easier for that user to pick at least one useful tag?

Is it possible to make a Ask Question button somewhere in the tag wiki UI, or let the Ask Question button take over the tag from the wiki you are viewing?

Comment: Well, the Ask Question page already [accepts tags on the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=onedrive), so it's just matter of putting a link in there. Should be easy enough. :)